# Read PDF annotation content using PDFSharp "Result View" Content C#

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, comments, pdfsharp

I'm trying to read the contents of all annotations in a PDF document using PDFSharp while keeping track of which page they are on.  The "contents" that I'm trying to retrieve is in the "Result View" of the PdfItem where it says "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"

I'm using the following code:

```
private void LoadCommentList(string file) //using pdfsharp
    {
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            page = inputDoc.Pages[i];
            page = document.AddPage(page);

            for (int p = 0; p < document.Pages[i].Annotations.Elements.Count; p++)
            {
                PdfItem textAnnot = document.Pages[i].Annotations.Elements.GetObject(p);
                //add specific item in "Results View" to CommentList here......
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I read through the "Results View" programatically so that I can get the contents of the PDF annotation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: foreach? ToList()? what exactly do you need?

Comment: foreach would work just fine.  Ultimately I need to get the information stored in the item with a label of "/Content"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be an easier way to accomplish this than the method I was trying.  Instead of using the Pdfitem object use PdfAnnotation object instead.  Should have done that from the beginning.  Code example below:

```
private void LoadCommentList(string file) //using pdfsharp
    {
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            page = inputDoc.Pages[i];
            page = document.AddPage(page);

            for (int p = 0; p < document.Pages[i].Annotations.Elements.Count; p++)
            {
                PdfAnnotation textAnnot = document.Pages[i].Annotations[p];

                string content = textAnnot.Contents;
                if (content != null)
                {
                    CommentList.Add(content);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```